# Issues with getting realpath while working with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am developing a web application.

My project is stored in

```
F:\Pro1\OHCMS
```

Now i want to upload a video in

```
F:\Pro1\OHCMS\Webcontent\Video
```

folder.

When i write

```
filePath=getServletContext().getRealPath("/Video")+"\\";
```

It is returning file path as

```
F:\Pro1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\OHCMS
```

How can i get the real path of my actual Webcontent folder ?

Comment: Did you deploy your web application to a web container? Try deploying it and print the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is being run by your IDE's default application server. That is, your WebContent folder  is actually copied to somewhere else (check out your build script to know where exactly is it copied). And after that, all your data is published to server.